# Capture exit code of multiline command

Tags: bash, shell, make

TLDR: How do I save the exit codes of `cmd1` and `cmd2` when running `cmd1 ; cmd2` in a Makefile?

More detail:

I am running `cmd1 ; cmd2` in a Makefile because I want `cmd2` to run even if `cmd1` fails.

`$?` is empty for `cmd1` and `cmd2`. Otherwise, I would have used: `cmd1 ; E1=$? ; cmd2 ; E2=$?`.

I have seen people recommend to use `a=$(cmd1)` to save the exit code to `a`, but for me `a` is empty as well.

Comment: What do you mean `$?` is empty?  `cmd1 ; E1=$? ; cmd2 ; E2=$?` should definitely work.  Are those variables not being set?

Comment: @jesse_b indeed the variables are not set (afaik). Running `cmd1 ; echo $? ; cmd2 ; echo $?` also prints two empty lines.

Comment: @jesse_b I am calling this within Makefile, but I assume that shouldnt make a difference

Comment: I think it might https://stackoverflow.com/q/16315089/8239155

Comment: ... it would at least need to be `$$?` to distinguish the shell variable from a make variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` as `$$` if you want it to be passed to the shell:

```
target:
    cmd1; e1=$$?; cmd2; e2=$$?; echo "cmd1 exited with $$e1, cmd2 with $$e2"; exit "$$(( e1 || e2 ))"
    echo only output if both cmd1 and cmd2 succeeded above
```

```
$ make target
cmd1; e1=$?; cmd2; e2=$?; echo "cmd1 exited with $e1, cmd2 with $e2"; exit "$(( e1 || e2 ))"
/bin/sh: 1: cmd1: not found
/bin/sh: 1: cmd2: not found
cmd1 exited with 127, cmd2 with 127
make: *** [Makefile:2: target] Error 1
```